# scala, Doobie, Postgres - how to continue application run if there is sql error during batch insert

Tags: sql, postgresql, scala, doobie

I have a simple `doobie` batch insert:

```
def insertMe(data: List[SomeData]): ConnectionIO[Unit] = {
  insert("Insert into some_table (name, age) values (data.name, data.age)")(data)
}

private def insert](sql: String)(data: List[String]): ConnectionIO[Unit] = Update[String](sql).updateMany(data.toList).void
```

It works fine where all data is correct. But when I get incorrect data (for example `name` length to long), I got SQL error and everything fails.
My goal is to continue application run even when error appears, obly log this info but do not abort it. I tried to do something like `continueOnError`, but `Doobie` does not have this one.
How it is possible to handle error when one `batch` fails and continue?

Comment: Have you checked this? https://tpolecat.github.io/doobie/docs/09-Error-Handling.html there are couple of suggestinos